# How to get MPEG Dash with DRM?

Tags: encryption, audio, drm, mpeg

Is possible download a MPEG Dash content with DRM?

How can I decrypt using the MPD file?

I tried download all M4S segments (audio and video) but when I join the segments the video doesn't work properly.

The site is using Widevine platform for DRM.

I tried too youtube-dl and dash-proxy but again unsuccessfully.

I searched on Google but I didn't succeed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this does not appear to be a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible do download?

Yes, No different that downloading any other file.

> Is it possible to decrypt given key?

Again, yes. may tools can do this.

> Is it possible to decrypt if you don't know the key?

No. If you don't know the key, there is no way to play the file outside the browser, and there is no way to extract the key from the file